# ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, nvm

Every time I open a terminal window, I get this (even before typing anything):

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.1.2
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at https://nodejs.org/
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v4.1.2 --silent` to unset it.
```

I was never running a version of node 4, but anyway I deleted node.js completely following some pretty thorough steps I found online, and then reinstalled it from the website to version 8.11.2 (`node -v` gives me v8.11.2) but the warning still appears

I never paid it much attention until my npm started seriously acting up while trying to work with create-react, giving me tons of security warning with `npm audit` and not letting me update to the indicated versions of modules.

I've tried everything, reinstalling npm, reinstalling node, etc. and I'm worried that it's interfering with my app now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(nvm maintainer here)

If you can get `node` working such that `nvm current` doesn't say "none" or "system", then you can run `nvm install-latest-npm` to ensure you have the latest version of npm that actually works on your node version.

Separately, node 4.1.2 is EOL - if that's your system version, you may want to uninstall it completely.

If you're still having trouble, please file an issue on http://nvm.sh

Comment: I had the same error and tried `nvm install-latest-npm` but it wasn't sufficient for me. The issue was fixed when I changed the default by typing this at the shell: `nvm alias default v9.9.0`.